# LocalStorage Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 4</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="headerH1">
                <h1>Acceso y edad</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="aviso">
                <p>En esta web se queda registrado el acceso de los usuarios y su edad. Puedes añadir nuevos usuarios y también puedes consultar los usuarios ya inscritos con su correspondiente edad.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <div class="datos">
                    <div class="divNombre">
                        <label for="nombre">Introduce tu nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
                        <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="registro">
                        <p class="contenido">
                            Tu nombre es:
                        </p>
                        <div class="divEdad">
                            <input type="number" id="edad" name="edad">
                            <button class="añadirEdad">Añadir Edad</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tablaRegistro">
                    <p>Puedes consultar quien se ha registrado en esta Web:</p>
                    <button class="consultar">Consultar</button>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Edad</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Archivo Javascript

```
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);

function main() {

    let botonEnviar = document.querySelector("#enviar");

    let botonConsultar = document.querySelector(".consultar");

    botonEnviar.addEventListener("click", function() {

        // Variables
        let botonEdad = document.querySelector(".añadirEdad");
        let contenido = document.querySelector(".contenido");
        let edad = document.querySelector(".divEdad");
        let valorInput = document.querySelector("#nombre").value;

        // Checkear valores
        if (localStorage.getItem('nombre') === valorInput) {
            contenido.style.display = "block";
            edad.style.display = "none";
            localStorage.setItem("nombre", valorInput);
            contenido.innerHTML = `La edad de ${localStorage.getItem('nombre')} es ${localStorage.getItem('edad')}`;
        } else {
            if (valorInput === "") {
                alert("No puedes quedar el campo vacio");
                return false;
            }
            contenido.style.display = "block";
            contenido.innerHTML = "No existe registro de dicha persona";
            edad.style.display = "block";
            localStorage.setItem('nombre', valorInput);
            botonEdad.addEventListener("click", function() {

                let valorEdad = document.querySelector("#edad").value;
                localStorage.setItem('edad', valorEdad);

            })
        }
    })
    botonConsultar.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let fila = document.createElement("tr");
        for (let i = localStorage.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            pintarTabla(value, fila);
        }

    })

}

function pintarTabla(valor, fila) {

    let tabla = document.querySelector("table");
    let nuevoTd = document.createElement("td");
    nuevoTd.innerHTML = valor;
    fila.appendChild(nuevoTd);
    tabla.appendChild(fila);

}
```

el problema es que a la hora de meter los datos en la tabla, solo me guarda el registro del ultimo añadido, no se me quedan guardado los demás. Tengo que coger los datos introducidos en el input para añadirlos al localStore y incluso si cerrase el navegador, se quedasen guardados en la tabla los datos introducidos.

He estado mirando distintas formas de realizarlo pero no he sido capaz de encontrar ninguna solución.

¿Como seria para que se me quedasen guardados todos las personas que introduzca?

Cuando cierro el navegador y vuelvo a entrar solo me ha quedado guardado el ultimo registro

Gracias y espero una solucion..